# SOAP request object containing null values

Tags: soap, asp.net-core, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to implement a SOAP web service in ASP.NET Core. I generated the proxy code with `dotnet svcutil` and a sample request with SoapUI.

The problem is that whenever I try to post the request to my service, the request object I get is not null, but all its values are. Specifically, I am testing it with an object of this class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.3")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="riceviPrenotazione", WrapperNamespace="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class riceviPrenotazioneRequest
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public prenotazione arg0;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public infoUtente arg1;

    public riceviPrenotazioneRequest()
    {
    }

    public riceviPrenotazioneRequest(prenotazione arg0, infoUtente arg1)
    {
        this.arg0 = arg0;
        this.arg1 = arg1;
    }
}
```

This is the proxy implementation:

```
public class FederFarma : FarPreSaEsterniWs
{
    public Task<riceviPrenotazioneResponse> riceviPrenotazione(riceviPrenotazioneRequest request)
    {
        // code...
    }

    public Task<eliminaPrenotazioneResponse> eliminaPrenotazione(eliminaPrenotazioneRequest request)
    {
        // code...
    }

    public Task<verificaDisponibilitaResponse> verificaDisponibilita(verificaDisponibilitaRequest request)
    {
        // code...
    }
}
```

The function being called is the first one (`riceviPrenotazione`). Its parameter (`request`) is not null, but `arg0` and `arg1` are.

This is my interface:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.3")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/", ConfigurationName="FarPreSaEsterniWs")]
public interface FarPreSaEsterniWs
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/FarPreSaEsterniWs/riceviPrenotazioneRequest", ReplyAction="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/FarPreSaEsterniWs/riceviPrenotazioneResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<riceviPrenotazioneResponse> riceviPrenotazione(riceviPrenotazioneRequest request);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/FarPreSaEsterniWs/eliminaPrenotazioneRequest", ReplyAction="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/FarPreSaEsterniWs/eliminaPrenotazioneResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<eliminaPrenotazioneResponse> eliminaPrenotazione(eliminaPrenotazioneRequest request);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/FarPreSaEsterniWs/verificaDisponibilitaRequest", ReplyAction="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/FarPreSaEsterniWs/verificaDisponibilitaResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<verificaDisponibilitaResponse> verificaDisponibilita(verificaDisponibilitaRequest request);
}
```

And this is the XML I'm sending via SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:far="http://farpresa.esterni.ised.it/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <far:riceviPrenotazione>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <anagrafica>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <cellulare>3333333333</cellulare>
               <codice>123</codice>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <codiceFiscale>RSSMRA01A00L885A</codiceFiscale>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <cognome>Rossi</cognome>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <comuneDiNascita>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <codice>L885</codice>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <descrizione>Vignola</descrizione>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <fiscale>L885</fiscale>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <nazione>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <codice>ITA</codice>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <descrizione>Italia</descrizione>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <fiscale>ITA</fiscale>
                  </nazione>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <provincia>MO</provincia>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <regione>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <codice>ER</codice>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <descrizione>Emilia-Romagna</descrizione>
                  </regione>
               </comuneDiNascita>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <domicilioCap>41057</domicilioCap>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <domicilioComune>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <codice>F257</codice>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <descrizione>Modena</descrizione>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <fiscale>F257</fiscale>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <nazione>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <codice>ITA</codice>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <descrizione>Italia</descrizione>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <fiscale>ITA</fiscale>
                  </nazione>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <provincia>MO</provincia>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <regione>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <codice>ER</codice>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <descrizione>Emilia-Romagna</descrizione>
                  </regione>
               </domicilioComune>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <domicilioIndirizzo>Via Finta, 12</domicilioIndirizzo>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <nome>Mario</nome>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <sesso>M</sesso>
            </anagrafica>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <codice>111</codice>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <listaPrenotato>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <prestazione>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <codice>222</codice>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <codiceRegionale>222</codiceRegionale>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <descrizione>Niente di che</descrizione>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <specialita>Nullafacentismo</specialita>
               </prestazione>
               <prezzoUnitario>10</prezzoUnitario>
               <quantita>1</quantita>
            </listaPrenotato>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <NRE>080A01234567890</NRE>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <note>Boh</note>
            <prezzoTotale>10</prezzoTotale>
         </arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nomeUtente>username</nomeUtente>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <password>password</password>
         </arg1>
      </far:riceviPrenotazione>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

According to what I found online, this seems a namespace problem, but all namespaces seem okay to me - SoapUI is consistent with the auto-generated classes, and most importantly they were generated from the same WSDL and not modified. What could be the cause?

Comment: How did you implement SOAP Service in .net core? Share us the soap service in the .net core. Do you follow [Custom ASP.NET Core Middleware Example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/19/custom-asp-net-core-middleware-example/)?

Comment: I'm using a NuGet package called SoapCore. All it requires you to do is adding the SOAP service during configuration, like this:

(in ConfigureServices)
ˋservices.AddSingleton<InterfaceImplementationClass>();ˋ

(in Configure)
ˋapp.UseSoapEndpoint<InterfaceImplementationClass>("/ServicePath.svc", new BasicHttpBinding());ˋ

Comment: What is the service defination? Share us code related with service.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same issue as mentioned on github: https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore/issues/79 I assume from the comments you are using SoapCore

Answer was:
Just needed to change DataContractSerializer to XmlSerializer in startup:

```
app.UseSoapEndpoint<MyService>("/MyService.svc", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer);
```

for this:

```
app.UseSoapEndpoint<MyService>("/MyService.svc", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
```

That solution worked for me.

Comment: XmlSerializer -> interface/classes generated via wsdl.exe
DataContractSerializer -> genertated via svcutil
XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer -> generated via dotnet-svcutil depending on switch used